# problem of selecting words in an array with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1['Catégorie']=="Advantage RH''",:]
```

I would like to select all the words of advantage rh which is in a table

exemple:
Advantage RH
Advantage RH\ARH
Demande de service\SIRH\Formation
Advantage RH\Déclaratif\DSN_phase 3_DSN Mensuelle
Advantage RH\Paie\Paramétrage\Rubrique
Advantage RH\Paie\Paramétrage\Congés payés

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I would like to select all the words of advantage rh which is in a table

Comment: tnks ,it's good